# Updating weights in backpropagation algorithm

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I think I've understood each step of backpropagation algorithm but the most important one. How do weights get updated? Like at the end of this tutorial? http://home.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with NN implemenation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The weight updates are done via the equations written at the last part of the page ([Backpropagation](http://home.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html)) you provided.
Let me elaborate a little bit:

**New Weights = Old Weights - learning-rate x Partial derivatives of loss function w.r.t. parameters**

For a given weight, calculate the [image] (which can be done easily by back propagating the error) which is nothing but the steepest direction of the function and subtract a scaled version of it, the scale factor being the step size or how large step you want to make in that direction.
Just a little clarification which I felt you might need after looking at the way you asked the question ...

**What is exactly Back-propagation?**

Backpropagation is just a trick to quickly evaluate the partial derivatives of the loss function w.r.t. all weights. It has nothing to do with weight updating. Updating the weights is a part of gradient descent algorithm.

Comment: why is it New_Weight = Old_Weight MINUS... instead of Old_Weight PLUS...?

Comment: @datdinhquoc It depends on how you've calculated the error/loss. For eg. If you did `obtained_value - target values`, you need to add the weights, otherwise subtract them.